# How much additional load does a multicast subscriber impose on a switch?

Tags: networking, multicast

If you have a switch with at least one subscriber to a multicast address, how much additional load would each additional subscriber add?

Example:
You have a 10G switch (with IGMP) with 10 servers and no other activity.
When Server1 subscribers to a 1G multicast feed, the switch will have 1G of load.
What would the load be after Server2 and Server3 subscribed?
Obviously traffic to the switch would not increase, but what about the switch's internal load?

Houw would the answer be different without IGMP?

Comment: 'Load' might be the wrong term.  I'm wondering more like this:
If you had a 10G switch, and 10 servers subscribed to the same 1G multicast and one server opened a 1G TCP stream, you would expect there to be no problem getting the data to the switch (2G/10G).  

But could you have trouble inside the switch itself?  I suspect this might be obvious to someone with a better understanding of how switches work.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of multicast is that it is efficient. The presence of one subscriber downstream causes the switch to send an IGMP join request of its own upstream and pass incoming multicasts downstream, without duplication. The addition of further downstream subscribers has no effect at all except to increment an internal subscriber count for that group. When that goes back to zero it sends an IGMP leave request of its own upstream.

I don't know what you mean by 'without IGMP'. There is no such thing as UDP multicast without IGMP. It is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I remember reading something that indicated that without IGMP data would be broadcast to everyone on the switch whether they had joined or not.  I could have misunderstood.

Comment: @Sherman That statement is either comparing multicast to broadcast or describing the behaviour of a switch without IGMP support as described in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, some background information for you.

The traditional definition of routers and switches are along the lines of:

- Router: a device capable of routing a packet form one IP subnet to a different IP subnet
- Switch: a device capable of switching a packet within the same IP subnet

However, this traditional definition no longer holds these days because we have switches that can route traffic from one IP subnet to another IP subnet and even perform complex operations such as QoS at wire speed.

Therefore it is often easier to redefine Routers and Switches as follows:

- Router: a device that uses the CPU to route packets, often inspects parts of packets that are higher up the OSI layer.
- Switch: a device with ASIC(s) (a.k.a switching chips) that switches/routes traffic at full wire speed. What this means is that if the switch has 24 1Gbps ports, it will be able to switch 24Gbps bi-directional traffic without dropping any packets.

Now, to answer your question, it is important to determine whether the ASIC in your switch is capable of handling multicast traffic or not. If so, adding "load" really isn't an issue, as long as you ensure that each switch port is not congested (e.g. 2Gbps of traffic trying to egress out of 1Gbps port). If the ASIC in your switch is NOT capable of handling multicast traffic, it is highly likely that the switch will simply send all multicast traffic up to the CPU. Then it would be up to the software to determine where each packet goes. CPUs on switches are not powerful, because their primary role isn't to route/switch packets, but to *manage* the switch (e.g. configure the ASIC so that packets get switched properly). Therefore, if your switch is sending packets up to the CPU, the switch will struggle. You won't get anywhere near 1Gbps of multicast via the CPU.

Without IGMP, switches, by default, will flood out the traffic on all ports. Again, this is not a problem for the switch itself because it can handle this at wirespeed. It may cause problems for other parts of the network because traffic is needlessly being duplicated.

The reason for this long answer is because the phrase "10G switch" in your example is quite misleading, and it led me to believe that you maybe thinking that a powerful CPU sits at the center of the switch that is capable of performing 10Gbps bi-directional switching. This is simply not the case, and talking about "load" on a switch therefore often makes little sense.

I hope this helps.